# This app is incompatible with this iPhone (iPhone 3G iOS 4.2.1)

Tags: iphone, app-store, installation, app-store-connect

I've recently put up a free app in the app store, which seems to work fine for most users. But I have received some reports from users telling me that "This app is incompatible with this iPhone" for users running iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1.

This is what the binary details looks like in the iTunes connect

> App Name :    XXXXXXXXX
>
> Apple ID :    XXXXXXXXX
>
> Bundle Identifier : XXXXXXXXX
>
> Localizations :   ( "en" )
>
> Prerendered Icon Flag :   false
>
> Original Zip File Name :  XXXXXXXXX.ipa
>
> Bundle Short Version String : 1.0
>
> Bundle Version :  1.0.13
>
> Minimum OS Requirements :     4.0
>
> Build SDK :   9A334
>
> Build Platform :  9A334
>
> Required Capabilities :   armv6 armv7
>
> Supported Architectures :     armv6, armv7
>
> Device Family :   iPhone / iPod
>
> Touch Newsstand App :     false
>
> Entitlements :    XXXXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXXXX
> get-task-allow: false
> keychain-access-groups: ( XXXXXXXXX )
> application-identifier: XXXXXXXXX

Which I think looks very accurate.

I can also add that the same application built with another provisioning profile works perfect on the same device when installing it OTA.

If you have an idea, please let me know.

Comment: which deployment Target did you set?

Comment: I have 3 targets in my project, which are the actual application, one for test cases and one which is a shell script. And when building and archiving I'm using the Release configuration.

Comment: i mean which "iOS Deployment Target" did you set in "build settings"

Comment: iOS Deployment Target is set to 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My updated application has just been approved by apple, and I can now install the app on iPhone 3G (iOS version 4.2.1).

What caused the problem is that the **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities** is by default set to armv7 only, I added armv6 to it but I realized that it won't help.

In my 1.0.1 version I just removed the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities completely and it now works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually build the submitted app with armv6 and armv7 listed in both "Valid Architectures" and "Architectures" in your app's Target Build setting for the Release or Distribution build?

Comment: +1 for correct answer - very likely the OP did not include arm6 building.

Comment: Sorry to make you disappointed, Architectures and Valid Architectures are both set to armv6 armv7, as the Binary Details in iTunes Connect shows. (See original question above)